# Study limit of a two variable function for every point of domain

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/f(x,y)=y^2-2x^2y+6x^3-3xy+2y-6x$$

I need to show that: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)}{y-3x}$ exists.

So:  $f(x,y)=y^2-2x^2y+6x^3-3xy+2y-6x=(y-3x)(y-2x^2+2)$

Then:  $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)}{y-3x}=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}(y-2x^2+2)$

However, I don't know how to proceed to do this for every $(x_0,y_0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function $y - x^2 + 2 $ is defined for every finite x and y (since the function is polynomial of $x$ and $y$), the limit exists. I think this argument solves the problem

Comment: Ok, i initially thought the same, but looks too easy, so i feel quite insecure about that.

Comment: @Wyvern666   This is correct because limits always exist for polynimial functions when the variables tend to finite values

Answer (score 1):

We can use the definition of limit. From this point of view, we need to show that for any $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there exists $L\in \mathbb{R}$ that (depends on $(x_0,y_0)$ and) satisfies the following condition:

> Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that
>   $$\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\delta\quad \Rightarrow\quad \left|\frac{f(x,y)}{y-3x}-L\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Here, $\|\cdot\|$ denotes a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For convenience, we will assume that $\|\cdot\|$ is the maximum norm.

Well, for each $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, take $L=y_0-2x_0^2+2$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$ we can take
$$\delta=\frac{1}{2}\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{3+4|x_0|}\right\}$$
and conclude that
$$\begin{align*} \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad \left|\frac{f(x,y)}{y-3x}-L\right|&=\left|y-2x^2-y_0+2x_0^2\right|\\
&\leq|y-y_0|+2|x^2-x^2_0|\\
&=|y-y_0|+2|x-x_0||x+x_0|\\
&<\delta+2\delta|x-x_0+x_0+x_0|\\
&\leq\delta+2\delta^2+4\delta|x_0|\\
&\leq\delta(3+4|x_0|)\\
&<\varepsilon.
\end{align*}$$